# How to access current firebase user from iOS Today Extension?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, today-extension

We're building a today widget on top of our iOS app which is working with Firebase. However we're struggling to access current signed-in user from the extension. The user at the main app is anonymous so passing credentials via shared container is not an option.

The only way that I found is passing uid and generate custom token to sign in but I was hoping to find out better way to share FIRUser between my main app and app extension. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: did you come up with a good solution for this?

Comment: Not really, we create another guest user for the widget. The issue here is there is no parameter to pass to authenticate same guest user. So it's a bit of duplication but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between `Host App` and `App Extension` only using `App Group`.
There is no way of direct communication between your `Host App` and `App Extension`.

> Even though an app extension bundle is nested within its containing
>   app’s bundle, the running app extension and containing app have no
>   direct access to each other’s containers.

`App Group` is a `shared container` used by both `Host App` as well as `App Extension`. It is like `UserDefaults` that store `key-value pairs`.

So you can save your current user information in `App Group` from `Host App` and then access it in your `Today Extension` from the same `App Group`.

For more on `App Groups` refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html