# Transfer Data From Apple Watch To iPhone in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3, apple-watch

I have been trying for multiple hours to find a way to send a global variable from the Apple Watch to the iPhone.

There are a lot of questions abut transferring data from iPhone to Apple Watch but not vice versa in Swift 3.

This is not a duplicate because I want to transfer data from the Apple Watch to iPhone, not vice Versa.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass text from iOS label to WatchOS label - swift-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673494/pass-text-from-ios-label-to-watchos-label-swift)

Comment: How can open open watch app from iPhone with watch connectivity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transferring data from Apple Watch to iPhone is very similar to vice versa.

For global variable you probably should use `updateApplicationContext()` of `WCSession`:

```
let session = WCSession.default()
if session.activationState == .activated {
    session.updateApplicationContext(["my_global": g_myGlobal])
}
```

On the iPhone you should assign delegate to the default `WCSession` and activate it. In the `WCSessionDelegate`, implement the following method:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
    let receivedGlobal = applicationContext["my_global"] as? TypeOfTheGlobal
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage) but this will require iPhone to be reachable.

In general I would recommend you to follow Zak Kautz advice and read about [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity). This is the most common way to communicate between watch and phone.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [watch connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) framework, you can implement two-way communication.