# Firebase currentUser returns nil in iOS Today Extension while user is logged in

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

User is authorized in main app, and Firebase is initialized inside Today Extension:

```
// We check if FIRApp has already been configured with a static var, else it will crash...
    if !TodayViewController.isAlreadyLaunchedOnce {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        TodayViewController.isAlreadyLaunchedOnce = true
    }
```

I've enabled Keychain Sharing as well and 2 times the currentUser property has returned the correct user but after that it always returns 'nil'

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
```

Is there something extra that should be done to make it working?

P.S. it's not related to guest user and there is not answer here:
[How to access current firebase user from iOS Today Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635989/how-to-access-current-firebase-user-from-ios-today-extension)
that's why it's not duplicate.
I can't solve the problem by creating a duplicate user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm faced with the same problem. Currently I dealt with it by copying the data contained in Keychain. This works, but I cannot say this is a valid solution.

https://gist.github.com/hhyyg/c1481853bcac27a678f707c0d1afd0f4

Comment: Thanks for answer! Trying to make it working at the moment. Could you please suggest from which fields the placeholders should be replaced? firebase_auth_{hosted app firebase application id}, firebase_auth_{app extension firebase application id}, firebase_auth_1___FIRAPP_DEFAULT_firebase_user - I've tried almost everything from GoogleService-Info.plist with no luck. Examples would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, finally it works! {hosted app firebase application id} = GOOGLE_APP_ID from GoogleService-Info.plist, __FIRAPP_DEFAULT works by default. Requires shared Keychain with the same group name.

Comment: This solution works for me. Using it a SiriKit extension

Answer (score 1):

There 2 things that should be done to make it working:

1. Share the same GoogleService-Info.plist between 2 projects (just don’t create separate as recommended, check your app extension in Target Membership in original one)
2. Enable Keychain Sharing

Firebase shows some warning like:

> 4.9.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000008] The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist',
>   or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options.
>   To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to
>   make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you
>   may change your app's bundle identifier to 'net.mybundle.mybundle’. Or
>   you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle
>   identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the
>   current one.

but works good so far..

P.S. sometimes changing GoogleService-Info.plist isn’t recognized by XCode and it uses old one. Make sure that you have the warning like “The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID” … if no - try to disable app extension membership in all GoogleService-Info.plist and run the project (it should fail on Firebase initialization in app extension) after that just re-enable app extension membership and run one more time.

Comment: There are one problem with this solution: after re-login in main app Today Extension is still logged in with old user.